# DAX Formula to Get Sales From X Highest Date Transactions in a Month

Tags: dax

I have a table of sales and the salesperson gets paid a higher commission rate on the number of transactions he does (Y) over Z transactions.

So I need to Sum the sales amount on the last Z minus Y transactions and I am drawing a blank.

My attempt:

```
SalesOver:= CALCULATE(
    SUM(Transactions[Sales]),
        TOPN(Z - Y,
            Transactions,
            Transactions[SaleDate], DESC,
            Transactions[Sales], DESC)
    )
```

I get a value but it is not correct.

Comment: I've just tried your formula with my own sample data and (once I had corrected the missing 's' on the end of the first 'Transaction') it works for me. Have you checked the "Y" and "Z" values getting passed through are correct? Can you share your sample data to show how it isn't working in your case?

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it works for you. It seems I have a filter context issue that I can't describe. I'm thinking I need ALL in that somewhere.